# how to write custom intellij tips messageboxes?

Tags: intellij-idea

I love the tips given by intellij.  I woudl like to add my own set of tips.  I did a search in google and here in stackoverflow and could not find any results for how to write such custom tips.

1. Is it possible to have custom message boxes with tips in intellij?
2. Is it possible to publish them so that a set of users can download and view these additional tips.
3. These should be **additional** tips to the tips that intellij already provides and not replace them!

Comment: do you mean *custom message boxes* without the need to write an **IntelliJ plugin**? What rules will use the IDE to show those messages then?

Comment: yes i thought maybe intellij provided someway of a file i can update and it would take every time a random row from that file...  or just a textbox in intellij settings i could fill in many rows and it would enable me to customize it.